# How can I create function for database activities and call them in controller in Laravel 5.1

Tags: php, mysql, oop, laravel-5.1

I have created a Model names `Contest.php` and created a function `createContest` for insert data in database (in contests table):

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Contest extends Model
{   
    public function createContest($request) {
        return $this->insert($request); 
    }

}
```

And I have a function `store` in `ContestController.php`:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $this->createContest($request);
}
```

How can I call `createContest` function of my model from my controller.

**I actually want to define all my database queries in my model, and can call them in my controller, I have not much idea about this flow, can some one please help me to understand the flow**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you can use Dependency Injection like as

```
use App\Contest as ContestModel;

class ContestController extends Controller
{   

    protected $contest;

    public function __construct(ContestModel $contest){
        $this->contest = $contest;
    }

    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $this->contest->createContest($request);
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, that is exactly what I was looking for. Can you please help me a bit more. I am new in laravel 5, I meed to insert data in database that is in `$request` variable as it is an instance of request so I can not send it directly for insertion, can you please tell me how could I insert data after validation of request

Comment: You can go through [Laravel Validation Docs](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/validation) they've well defined the whole working over there

Answer (score 0):

You can make the function of your Model static:

```
public static function createContest($request){...}

Contest::createContest($request);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use

```
Contest::createContest($request);
```

but remember to include

```
use App\Contest;
```

at the beginning of your controller.

And declaring createContest as static as W.Steve said

```
public static function createContest($request)
```

because you're calling a class function.

Comment: If I need to call `Contest` like `Contest::functionName` then why I'll create functions in model. I can directly call the `Contest::insert($postData)` in my controller. Actually I do not want to call `Contest` class in my controller again and again. I had read some where a block of code on which he was was calling his model functions by using `$this`. I am not aware with this flow, I think I need to create constructor or something else.